# XMLBuilder adds the attributes to wrong node in the XML file

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml-builder

I am creating the XML files in `Node.js` using the `XMLBuilder` package. Everything is working fine except for one thing. I am trying to add attributes to `root` element but for some reason, it gets added to `child` element.

I have declared my `root` element like this:

```
//Create the header for XML
var builder     =   require('xmlbuilder');

var root        =   builder.create('test:XMLDocument')
                            root.att('schemaVersion', "2.0")
                            root.att('creationDate', '2020-10-09T09:53:00.000+02:00')
                            root.att('xmlns:xsi', "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
root            =   root.ele('MyBody')
root            =   root.ele('MyEvents')
```

After the declaration when I try to add some more attributes to my root elements:

```
root.att('new1','additionalAttributes1')
root.att('new2','additionalAttributes2')
```

It is getting appended to the `MyEvents` and looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test:XMLDocument schemaVersion="2.0" creationDate="2020-10-09T09:53:00.000+02:00">
    <MyBody>
        <MyEvents new1="additionalAttributes1" new2="additionalAttributes2">
        </MyEvents>
    </MyBody>
</test:XMLDocument>
```

But I am expecting the generated XML file to appear something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test:XMLDocument schemaVersion="2.0" creationDate="2020-10-09T09:53:00.000+02:00" new1="additionalAttributes1" new2="additionalAttributes2">
    <MyBody>
        <MyEvents>
        </MyEvents>
    </MyBody>
</test:XMLDocument>
```

I am aware that if I declare my XML element like this then I am able to achieve the expected result but as I am passing it to another function I am unable to declare it like this:

```
//Create the header for XML
var builder             =   require('xmlbuilder');

var root        =   builder.create('test:XMLDocument')
                            root.att('schemaVersion', "2.0")
                            root.att('creationDate', '2020-10-09T09:53:00.000+02:00')
                            root.att('xmlns:xsi', "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
                            
root.att('new1','additionalAttributes1')
root.att('new2','additionalAttributes2')

root            =   root.ele('MyBody')
root            =   root.ele('MyEvents')
```

I tried adding the .up() to see if it gets added to parent but no luck. Can someone please help me how can I add the attributes to parent when I have multiple child and achieve the required results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just have to go up twice

```js
var builder = require('xmlbuilder')
var root = builder.create('test:XMLDocument')
root.att('schemaVersion', '2.0')
root.att('creationDate', '2020-10-09T09:53:00.000+02:00')
root.att('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')
root = root.ele('MyBody')
root = root.ele('MyEvents')

root = root.up().up()
root.att('new1','additionalAttributes1')
root.att('new2','additionalAttributes2')

console.log(root.end({pretty: true}));
```

output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test:XMLDocument schemaVersion="2.0" creationDate="2020-10-09T09:53:00.000+02:00" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" new1="additionalAttributes1" new2="additionalAttributes2">
  <MyBody>
    <MyEvents/>
  </MyBody>
</test:XMLDocument>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. This is working as expected.